# Multiple Azure Directories

Tags: azure, user-profile

I Initially posted this to azure DevOps, who referred me to Azure.

I thought to make things clear with additional info.

The problem is, and My licensing, tenant, and repository access is affected by this.

I have set up an azure DevOps tenant many moons ago and through there connected through to Github. My cellular was stolen with the 2FA app, which Githjub has decided would be one of two mechanisms to regain access to on the account. All my Microsoft services are connected to the Microsoft account, but that email is locked in GitHub onto a profile that I cannot get access to. The other option available is to have a piece of paper that you carry everywhere you go. First I have to buy a printer.

I followed a post stating the difference between default directory and MS account and it was mentioned that it should be one and the same.

In my instance, I am connected to four directories. One named 'Default Directory', where I was able to upload a new avatar. There are some projects hosted there that I had set up many years ago when Azure launched. It is however not the same as the Microsoft Account (see different avatar and not linked to the default directory in terms of subscriptions and repositories). The latter is empty. It uses the same Microsoft email bett…com. I want to make use of the Azure services in order to learn and get certifications but for example, The Visual Studio subscription is tied to the default directory, but when I log into visual studio, I log into my Microsoft account. I did notice the move towards one account for all - it is coming together nicely.

I had set up a tenant for a company named Pandoran as a demo, early last year. The owner has passed away from COVID recently and the company was taken over by someone else. As an administrator, I was able to reset the tenant but cannot delete it or disassociate my ID from the tenant. An error is thrown. And there is an annoying option in the directory drop-down. For security sake and if someone manages to access the tenant and run up a bill.  So many things can happen.

Similarly, I was associated with a company called Intervate. Intervate was bought over by T-Systems. They traded for a while but the company as an entity do no longer exists. I would like my ID to be disassociated with them as well.

The intervate link was I suspect created as I linked my MCP profile to them as an MS partner. I cannot leave the organization. The pandoran account i have tried everything but i still cannot leave the organisation. The site hangs for a few ninutes on clicking the leave organisation link. And then we are back to the same business

I approached MS support, and the agent has not been able to resolve the issue and this then is my door into participating in the community. Exciting stuff!

Because of Github I have now more than one account that I try to manage or combine in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

When you say disassociate your ID with other tenants, is your account a guest account in AAD or an actual domain account for that tenant?

If its a guest account, you should be able to remove your association with the organisation in your own domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/leave-the-organization

Comment: It doesnt work, I did try.  The link asks you to log in to leave and then the leave button is not available or timesout.

Comment: I have also ghosts accounts (no username) that was used to sign agreements with in the partner profile